# XElement XML ToString malformed [ ]

Tags: c#, xml

So I m parsing some xml. I create my XElement and run the `ToString()` method. I look at the results and they are all wrong.

```
<root>[elementName, ElementValue ]</root>
```

When It should look like

```
<root>
  <data name="Name">
    <value>Value</value>
  </data>
</root>
```

This is really weird. I've used XML plenty of times and have never run into this. I have looked on the web and I can't find anything. When I step through the `XDocument` creation process the `ToString()` for each element is correct. What is going on? How can I troubleshoot this?

Here is my code

```
    string WriteXml(Dictionary<string, string> dic)
    {
        var root = new XElement("root");

        foreach (var pair in dic)
        {
            var element = new XElement("data", pair.Value);
            element.Add(new XAttribute("name", pair.Key));
            root.Add(pair);
        }

        var doc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null), root);

        var s = doc.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(s);

        return doc.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: You have to add your newly created element: `root.Add(element);`. Sidenote: you will never get what you want because you never created a child element `value`. Instead, you will get `<data name="Name">Value</data>`.

Comment: I think @JeroenVannevel got the point.

Comment: Yes, `Add(pair);` => `Add(element);`